# Spring boot on Google appengine standard - REST API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run my code on local appengine simulator through the command mvn appengine:run and there is no error, it is just that, it can't find any of the RestController (eg: **No file found for**: /setiaalam/amenities).

Also, there is **no Spring Boot logo** been display from the **startup**, so I suspect I need to specific the servlet init for it? It is running fine in my own Apache Tomcat Eclipse environment, but this is only working if I were to '**run**' the main class.

To be more specific, there is no custom servlet i'm creating, I just want to migrate it to Google Cloud AppEngine Standard - although no error, there is no Spring Boot startup logo at all. Trying to access any of the GET API that works locally using Postmen always return 404. No issue when try to access it from previous Apache Tomcat localhost.

Yes, I'm following the github guideline here:
[Link to Github for Spring boot Google Appengine Standard](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/3ce78bc3c3e8d841f025e21e162d11f274e06b8f/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard/README.md)

It didn't mention anything on modifying the web.xml.

And I missing something here?

Code (The main app):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class SetiaAlamApplication{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SetiaAlamApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Code(1 of the controller):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/setiaalam")
public class AmenityController {

@Autowired
AmenityDAO amenityDAO;

//service to get all amenities
@GetMapping("/amenities")
public List<Amenity> getAllAmenities(){
    return amenityDAO.findAll();
}
```

Code (The needed SpringBootServletInitializer):

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SetiaAlamApplication.class); 
 }
}
```

The application.properties:

```
# Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/setiaalam? 
useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
spring.datasource.username = hidden
spring.datasource.password = hidden

# Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen 
database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: This might be a package issue, usually you need to tell spring where to look for controllers. where did you locate your controllers? you might need to use the @ComponentScan annotation in the SetiaAlamApplication class

Comment: Hi @ItaiSoudry, thanks for the help. All of the controllers is located at the sub folder of SetiaAlamApplication class as advised by Spring boot practices....and it only needed to use ComponentScan annotation when it is at different package. Also, just curious, when is ServletInitializer  is been called because I just follow the example for the link I provided in github, there is no usage of it whether from web.xml or the pom.xml.

Comment: I actually never used servlet initializer. What is the console output when you run the SetiaAlamApplication main function?

Comment: I was advised to use Servlet Initializer by the Google App Engine guide. What do you mean by that? You mean to open another console and run the SetiaAlamApplication main function? By the way, if to follow exactly the guide to run locally, the command is mvn appengine:run. However, if I were to run using another command mvn spring-boot:run, I can see the Spring boot logo booted up but separate error occur (Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean).

Comment: Ok, some update. I follow the other example from Google, using Eclipse plugin for Google App Engine. Still the same issue of 404. [link](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging)

Comment: Ok, issue fixed. How I fix it? Download the latest Eclipse. This follow by updating it with Spring Tool feature. Then follow by Google Cloud Tool. Once added, create a new Spring project (through Eclipse as previously I didnt but using spring.io). Based on the generated single main application, change the needed configuration on the pom.xml according to the Google guide for Google App Engine Standard. Once done, create a simple 1 controller that return just a single String text. Deploy locally - on Jetty of course, once working, move 1 by 1 all the classes to this new project.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, issue fixed. How I fix it?

**Step 1**
Download the latest Eclipse.

**Step 2**
This follow by adding Spring Tool feature from the Eclipse Market. Please take note, if you can't find the Eclipse Market, you need to add that 1st. Simple google will guide you on how to do it.

**Step 3**
Then follow by adding Google Cloud Tool (from Eclipse Market).

**Step 4**
Once added, create a new Spring project (through Eclipse as previously I didn't but using spring.io).

**Step 5**
Based on the generated single main application, change the needed configuration on the pom.xml according to the Google guide for Google App Engine Standard.

**Step 6**
Once done, create a simple 1 controller that return just a single String text. Deploy locally - on Jetty of course, once working, move 1 by 1 all the classes to this new project.

**Important Notes**
Of course, if your project like mine that require more and extra dependency such as Google API, Hibernate, you need to manually add it into the pom.xml.
Also, for sure you will encounter the issue from Eclipse 'Unable to change Dynamic Web Module facet', i follow the simple guide of changing the project file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml accordinly to 3.0 for the jst.web.

Thanks